# Visibility binding

Tags: wpf, binding, windows-store-apps

I have this situation:

```
    <TextBlock x:Name="NoMonthDataTextBlock" 
                            Text="No data." 
                            Margin="20,10,0,0" 
                            Foreground="Black" 
                            FontWeight="Bold"
                            FontSize="20"
                            Visibility="{Binding SelectedSymbolItem.NoData, Converter={StaticResource FieldVisible}}"/>

<tools:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="FieldVisible" TrueValue="Visible" FalseValue="Collapsed" />

public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : BoolToValueConverter<Visibility>
    {
    }

    public class BoolToValueConverter<T> : IValueConverter
    {
        public T FalseValue { get; set; }
        public T TrueValue { get; set; }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return FalseValue;
            else
                return (bool)value ? TrueValue : FalseValue;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            return value != null ? value.Equals(TrueValue) : false;
        }
    }
```

The problem is when the `SelectedSymbolItem is null` the field is visible and I don't want that.

I want this textBlock to be visible only when the SelectedSymbolItem is not null and has empty data. 
I have thought about using Multibing but I'm targeting windows store apps(8.0) and is not supported here. (one condition for not null and another for no data.)

How can I make the textBlock to be Collapsed when SelectedSymbolItem is null?

Comment: FallbackValue="Collapsed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a FallbackValue of Collapsed ,
in your case this would work there would be a Binding error on the Visibility Property and it will take the supplied FallbackValue.

```
  <TextBlock x:Name="NoMonthDataTextBlock" 
                        Text="No data." 
                        Margin="20,10,0,0" 
                        Foreground="Black" 
                        FontWeight="Bold"
                        FontSize="20"
                        Visibility="{Binding SelectedSymbolItem.NoData,Converter={StaticResource FieldVisible},FallbackValue=Collapsed}"/>

  <tools:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="FieldVisible" TrueValue="Visible" FalseValue="Collapsed" />
```

Comment: Thank you @eran otzap, I didn't know about the fallback parameter.

Comment: The converter is a generic one, I didn't know how to do it. I will edit my question and put the converter code there.

Comment: Yes i just thought of that and edited my question , Fallback would be the way to go

Comment: I've added the converter. Please see now.